# Display temp div in view

Tags: javascript

I want to display a temp div based on my click. For example when I click on the second row, a temp div will show after the second row.

This is my view:

```
<div id="sidetree" align="center">
  <div id="sidetreecontrol">
    <a href="?#">Collapse All</a> | <a href="?#">Expand All</a>
  </div>
  <ul class="treeview" id="tree">
    <li class="expandable">
      <div class="hitarea expandable-hitarea"></div>
      <a href="?/index.cfm">These are the Sponsors Of <?=$sponsor_id;?></a>
      <ul style="display: none;">
      <?php
        foreach($Level1Details->result() as $row){
      ?>
        <li id="sponsor_id"><label alt="<?=$row->user_id?>"><?=$row->user_id;?></label></li>
        <ul><div id="levelTwo"></div></ul>
        <?php } ?>
```

And JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#sponsor_id label').live('click',function() {
    var sponsor_id=$(this).attr("alt");
    alert(sponsor_id);
    var js={"sponsor_id":sponsor_id};
    $.post(url+"loyalty/level2", js, function(data){
      $('#levelTwo').html(data.result);
      }, "json");
    });
```

Comment: and what is the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

May be this is something what you want:

```
$(yourDiv).click(function(){
    $('.tempdiv').remove();
    var tempDiv = $("<div/>").attr('class', 'tempdiv').css({"width": "100px". "height":100px"}).appendTo($(this));
});
```